# Detectar palabras clave en una palabra y mostrarla completa - PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código PHP:

```
<?php
$keys= "Nuevo Antivirus, este es llamado Anti-AllSafe";

// Encontramos esas "palabras clave"
if (strpos($keys, 'Anti') !== false) { $encontrado = true; }

if ($encontrado) {echo "";} // Justo aquí es donde muestre las coincidencias: "Antivirus y Antivirus-AllSafe"
else {echo ' Sin parecidos';} 
?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que sin importar cuantas veces aparezca la palabra Antivirus en todo el texto se autocomplete, ejemplo:

> Anti - Se complete automáticamente en: Antivirus

Y la segunda coincidencia se complete:

> Anti se complete en: Anti-AllSafe

En resumen, es la continuidad de esa palabra en pase a la 'palabra clave'. Agradezco me puedan ayudar en este problema, no se si lo estoy haciendo mal o hay una forma de hacerlo más efectivo,

Comment: No entiendo bien que es lo que quieres lograr.  Quieres contar cuantas veces ser repite la palabra clave o quieres autocompletar algo?

Comment: @alanfcm Autocompletar amigo, poe ejemplo 'Anti' se autocomplete con toda la palabra completa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear una expresión regular para buscar todas las palabras que contienen la `clave`

```
/[^\s,.]*(KEY)[^\s,.]*/i
```

Descripción de la RegExp

1. `[^\s,.]*`: cero o mas coincidencias de caracteres distinto de caractes vacios (`\s`), coma (`,`) y punto (`.`)
2. `(KEY)`: "clave" que debe contener
3. Idem `1`
4. `i`: bandera para indicar que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (*case insensitive*).

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$frase = "Nuevo Antivirus, este es llamado Anti-AllSafe";
$key = 'Anti';
$regex = '/[^\s,.]*'.preg_quote($key).'[^\s,.]*/i';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $frase, $matches)) {
   echo implode(', ' $matches[0]);
}
else {echo ' Sin parecidos';}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6026fae4462cff567bc190177b07809092ad09c6)</kbd>

---

#### Referencias:

- [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-quote.php)
- [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `str_replace` asi:

```
<?php
$keys= "Nuevo Antivirus, este es llamado Anti-AllSafe";

// Encontramos esas "palabras clave"
$new_keys = str_replace('Anti', 'Antivirus', $keys);

echo $new_keys; 
?>
```

Comment: Pero en el caso que sea una palabra distinta, ya que son datos traidos desde una BBDD
No hay forma de autocompletarla con la palabra exacta correspondiente?

Comment: Dependiendo de cuantas palabras sean puedes usar un array asociativo.